# Django Rest Framework not finding throttle scope?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Extrapolating from the example found in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/, I added the following settings to my DRF setup:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
    'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
    'project.api.throttles.AppEventRateThrottle',
),

'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': { # 86,400 seconds in a day
    'app_events': '10000/day',
    'anon': '10000/day',
    'user': '10000/day',
},
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'project.api.exception_handler.custom_exception_handler',
}
```

This is the simple `AppEventRateThrottle` class, located in `project.api.throttles`

```
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle

class AppEventRateThrottle(AnonRateThrottle):
     scope = 'app_events'
```

The simple function-based API view that I'm trying to throttle:

```
from project.api.throttles import AppEventRateThrottle
@api_view(['POST'])
@throttle_classes([AppEventRateThrottle])
def grouped_event_create(request):
    return Response("Hello, world!")
```

However, every time I make this API call, I get

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/throttling.py", line 94, in get_rate
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: No default throttle rate set for 'app_events' scope
```

It seems it cannot find the 'app_events' key in the `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES` dictionary, but it's clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing `@throttle_classes([AppEventRateThrottle])` to `@throttle_classes([AppEventRateThrottle,])`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding more information to this answer. Why and how does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @m00am it strong-types to an array.

Comment: @user3876538 it would be a list with or without the comma. The comma only applies to tuples.